# "EXPECTED_INTEGER","detail":"Expected an integer value.","field":"amount_money.amount"

Tags: php, square-connect

I already read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46078084/expected-integer-issues-with-square-payment-portal) and confirmed that I am sending a whole number `100` but for some reason I keep getting the error

I am receiving the charge amount from a `POST` like

```
$charge_amount = $_POST['charge_amount'];
```

then in my API I am sending it as

```
$request_body = array (
    "customer_id" => $customer->getId(),
    "customer_card_id" => $card->getId(),
    "amount_money" => array (
        "amount" => $charge_amount,
        "currency" => 'USD'
    ),
    "idempotency_key" => uniqid(),
);
```

but that didn't work. So I decided to change the value statically like so

```
$request_body = array (
    "customer_id" => $customer->getId(),
    "customer_card_id" => $card->getId(),
    "amount_money" => array (
        "amount" => 100,
        "currency" => 'USD'
    ),
    "idempotency_key" => uniqid(),
);
```

and that worked.

Why is the `POST` not working? I confirmed that the value of `100` is coming in through the post with `echo $charge_amount`. I even tried changing to `"amount" => "$charge_amount",` but that didn't work as well.

The error I am getting at the end of all this is

```
[HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request] {"errors":[{"category":"INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR","code":"EXPECTED_INTEGER","detail":"Expected an integer value.","field":"amount_money.amount"}]}
```

Comment: You just need to cast the value of charge_amount, to integer, with intval for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the data type of the variable in question using [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php), if it isn't INT, cast it as such by either [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting):

```
$my_string = (int) '100';
```

or using the function [`intval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

```
$my_string = intval('100');
```

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST['charge_amount']` is going to be the *string* `"100"`.

Cast to an integer by doing `$charge_amount = (int)$_POST['charge_amount'];` or `$charge_amount = intval($_POST['charge_amount']);` (the two are [functionally identical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912599/is-there-any-particular-difference-between-intval-and-casting-to-int-int-x), in this case)