# Does square accepts decimal values?

Tags: square-connect

i have read some issues regarding this but not clarified if they accept or not an amount with decimal value.

im a beginner to square. Please Help... Below is my error

errors
:
Array(1)
0
:
category
:
"INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR"
code
:
"EXPECTED_INTEGER"
detail
:
"Expected an integer value."
field
:
"amount_money.amount"

Answer (score 0):

The "amount" field is always in the lowest denomination for the currency being used. If you're using USD this would be in cents, for example. If you need to charge $1.50, then for the amount you will need to supply "150" in terms of cents.

Also asked here: [EXPECTED_INTEGER — Issues with Square payment portal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46078084/expected-integer-issues-with-square-payment-portal/46079490#46079490)

Comment: thank you for the quick reply.. just for clarification, so if i have an amount of $35.9 do i need to encode this as 359?

Comment: i think i got it.. so if i have an amount of $35.9 i need to multiply it by 100 to get the cent value is it? :) so it will become 3590

Comment: @Atiris that is correct! $35.90 will become 3590, and that is the value you will supply for the "amount" field.